# How do I put a condition on the subject line?

Tags: vba, outlook

I want to autosave attachments from a sub-folder in Outlook.

I need to only save those in mail with a particular subject line (inStr) and the time received, like today.

I have code, but don't know how to add the conditionals, the subject and time received; and I would like to rename the Excel attachment when I save it.

```
Option Explicit
Const folderPath = "C:\Documents\nike\My Documents\emailTest\"

Sub CompanyChange()

    On Error Resume Next
    Dim ns As NameSpace
    Set ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Dim Inbox As MAPIFolder
    Set Inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

    Dim searchFolder As String
    searchFolder = InputBox("What is your subfolder name?")

    Dim subFolder As MAPIFolder

    Dim Item As Object
    Dim Attach As Attachment
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim i As Integer

    If searchFolder <> "inbox" Then
        Set subFolder = Inbox.Folders(searchFolder)
        i = 0
        If subFolder.Items.Count = 0 Then
            MsgBox "There are no messages in the Inbox.", vbInformation, _
              "Nothing Found"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        For Each Item In subFolder.Items
            For Each Attach In Item.Attachments
                Attach.SaveAsFile (folderPath & Attach.FileName)   
                i = i + 1
            Next Attach
        Next Item

    Else
        i = 0
        If Inbox.Items.Count = 0 Then
            MsgBox "There are no messages in the Inbox.", _ 
              vbInformation, "Nothing Found"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        On Error Resume Next
        For Each Item In Inbox.Items
            For Each Attach In Item.Attachments
                FileName = folderPath & Attach.FileName
                Attach.SaveAsFile FileName
                i = i + 1
            Next Attach
        Next Item
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

**Like this:**

Place your if condition before the loop that is saving your files.

```
   For Each Item In subFolder.Items

        If Item.Subject = "Subject you want to Macth with" Then  'Condition

          For Each Attach In Item.Attachments

            Attach.SaveAsFile (folderPath & Attach.FileName)

             i = i + 1
          Next Attach

        End If

   Next Item
```